# Proof verification: if $A'$ contains all the limit points of $A$ then $A$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Say we have a set $A$ and let us define a set $A'$ which contains all the limit points of $A$. Prove that $A'$ is closed.

---

Here is my attempt, please tell me if it is correct:

Say $A'$ is not closed. Let x be limit point in A'.

Due to unclosed group definition
We can say there is an $x$ that doesnt belong to $A'$ and this $x$ is limit point in $A'$.l et e1>0. 
Due to limit point definition we have infinity number in  $A'$  part $(x+e1,x-e1)$
Due to  A' definition if X doesnt belong to A',it isnt limit point in A,which means we have finite numbers in the part (x+e1,x-e1)
Let a be limit point A.
Due to A' definition we can say there exist a in the part (x+e1) ,that mean a>x. Let e1= 2a-x. 
Due to a definition ,there are infinite numbers(at group A) in the part (a+e2,a-e2).Let e2= a/2,that means we have infinite numbers in the part (3a/2,a/2).
That mean we have infinite numbers in the part (x+e1,x-e1)=(2a,2x-2a) because it containt (3a/2,a/2). And that contradict what i said at the begining that we have finite numbers in this part.

Comment: By group, do you mean "set"?

Comment: You've assumed $A$ is metric?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is very confusing, for two reasons:

---

First of all, the language is horrible. I understand you are not a native speaker, but the english in your post is very unclear at some points. For example, I have *no* idea what the sentence

> Moreover, we have infinity number in  $A'$ $(x+e,x-e)$ (as limit point definition)

is supposed to mean.

---

Second of all, you made a mistake with saying

> Assume that $A'$ is not closed. This means there is an $x$ that doesnt belong to $A'$ and this $x$ is limit point in $A'$.

This statement is just false. The second sentence simply does not follow from the first.

Comment: i use one of the definition of limit point. if X is limit point that means,i can find infinite num in the part (x+e,x-e). i use the definition of close group,which is a group that contain all the limit points. if A' isnt closed that means we have X-limit point that doesnt belong to A'.

Comment: @MosheLevy What does that sentence mean? What does it mean to "find infinite num"? What is "num"? What is "infinite num"? What is e? What is (x-e, x+e)? An interval? If so, is $A$ a subset of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: E=epsilon. find infinite num(number) means that we have infinite numbers in the part. (x-e,x+e) is a part.(all the nums between x+e,x-e). im talking on R.

Comment: @MosheLevy OK, now that I explained why I can't understand your original argument, it's your turn to edit your question to make your proof more clear. Only then can I further comment on it.

Comment: I did the best i could,please tell me what you think.